# Excel INSTR to find hard return in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet where the Item description is a variable length but always finishes with a "hard return" to force a wrapped line in the cell. I need to copy the first line of the cell into another cell.

Can I use INSTR to find the first instance of a hard return (invisible character) and then copy the first N-1 characters?

For example:

```
Dell PowerEdge R720XD
Chassis (Max of ......
```

OR

```
Dell OptiPlex 7010 Minitower   
Intel Core.............
```

In all cases I need to copy the first line of the text in the cell, irrespective of length.

Any ideas how I could do this??

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can easily do this

```
strShort = Left(strLong, InStr(strLong, vbCrLf) - 1)
```

Some times (eep. when sourced from a Unix system), you might have to replace `vbCrLf` (carriage Return, LineFeed) with a `vbLf` only.

If you are not sure if it contains an Enter, this code will do

```
strShort = IIf(InStr(strLong, vbCrLf), Left(strLong, InStr(strLong, vbCrLf) - 2), strLong)
```

Comment: You need to use instr() - 1 in your first example otherwise you get the CR part of the CR/LF -- also it only works if there is a CRLF in your string.

Comment: @DanMetheus: Thanks for pointing that out, I updated the answer. Actually, `vbCrLf`is even two characters. Regarding the "works only if it contains a vbCrLf" - yes, that's why I proved the second example, taking care of that situation.

Comment: @KeithGraham: If you're happy with either solution, please accept one as an answer!

Comment: It's -1 in both situations since instr returns the start of the string regardless of if it is chr(13) or chr(13)+chr(10) if that makes any sense.

Comment: @DanMetheus: Dough! I should go to bed! Thx

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the type of line break you can do it this way:

```
InStr(Range("A1").Text, vbLf)
InStr(Range("A1").Text, vbCr)
InStr(Range("A1").Text, vbCrLf)
```

to get the text before the line break:

```
Left(Range("A1").Text, InStr(Range("A1").Text, vbLf) - 1)
```

to get the text after the line break:

```
Right(Range("A1").Text, InStr(Range("A1").Text, vbLf))
```

Comment: @peterAlbert - Thanks to you both for the prompt response. Turns out that a forced return in the excel cell is a vbLF character, not a vbCrLf. Once I'd worked that out it runs like a dream.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to add a comment to Ripster's code below.  I needed a reputation of 50; mine's only 36, but that's really where this comment should go instead of a separate answer.

It seems to me that the last bit of Ripster's code,

```
Right(Range("A1").Text, InStr(Range("A1").Text, vbLf))
```

should be,

```
Right(Range("A1").Text, (Len(Range("A1")-InStr(Range("A1").Text, vbLf)) - 1)
```

And finally to regenerate the string without the break

```
strString = Left(Range("A1").Text, InStr(Range("A1").Text, vbLf) - 1) & Right(Range("A1").Text, (Len(Range("A1")-InStr(Range("A1").Text, vbLf)) - 1)
```

A note to the moderators : Please review this.  I still consider mysefl as a beginner to VBA and my logic could be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

my solution is:

strString = Replace(strString, vbLf, "")

It is useful even if the string contains more than one line brakes.